# How to specify mapping alias for imports in a Node.js typescript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, importerror, ts-node

I have specified a mapping in the `tsconfig.json` file to import shared code -

```js
"paths": {
    "@shared/*": [
        "../shared/ts/*"
    ],
}
```

Complete `user-service/tsconfig.json` file:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*": [
                "../shared/ts/*"
            ],
        },
        "module": "commonjs",
        // "rootDir": "./",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

Folder structure of the project:

```
.
├── README.md
├── docker-compose-dev.yaml
├── shared
│   └── ts
│       ├── constants
│       │   ├── errorMessages.ts
│       │   └── statusMessages.ts <- #1
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── tsconfig.json
│       └── types
│           ├── configTypes.ts <- #2
│           └── sm.ts
├── start-dev.sh
└── user-service
    ├── Dockerfile.dev
    ├── Dockerfile.prod
    ├── build
    │   └── index.js
    ├── nodemon.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── src
    │   ├── config
    │   │   ├── config.ts
    │   │   ├── database.ts
    │   │   └── env.ts
    │   ├── dev.env
    │   └── index.ts <- #3
    └── tsconfig.json
```

But inside `index.ts` [#3], when I try to import a the file from `shared/constants/statusMessages` [#1], this shows error.
But importing `shared/types/configTypes` [#2] works.

`shared/tsconfig.json` file:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "composite": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

`index.ts` file:

```js
import express from 'express';
import ENV from './config/env';
import config from './config/config';

import { EnvConfig } from '@shared/types/configTypes'; // This import is working
import statusMessages from '@shared/constants/statusMessages'; // This import is not working
// import statusMessages from '../../shared/ts/constants/statusMessages';

const LOG = config[ENV.NODE_ENV].log();

const app = express();



LOG.info("Hello from user-service!");
LOG.info(statusMessages.STATUS_SUCCESS);

const PORT: number = 80;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    LOG.info(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

Error thrown:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@shared/constants/statusMessages'
Require stack:
```

start script:

```js
"start:dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./src/index.ts | \"./node_modules/.bin/bunyan\""
```

Console output:

```
$ npm run start:dev

> user-service@1.0.0 start:dev
> nodemon --legacy-watch ./src/index.ts | "./node_modules/.bin/bunyan"

[nodemon] 3.1.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,js,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts`
Error: Cannot find module '@shared/constants/statusMessages'
```

However the relative path import, that is commented out is working.

**How to fix the alias import error? Why this error is coming only from the single import, not the other?**

If I miss to provide any information, please comment.

I tried to use relative path for import, this worked. But I want to use alias import.